How to edit a k8s daemonset yaml automatically in GitHub Actions environment?
I want to edit the daemonset yaml file in a github actions environment.
In a normal environment we can use the kubectl edit daemonset -n kubearmor (kubearmor is the namespace) command to open a vi/nano instance and edit, then save the changes.
I want to add the flag -enableKubeArmorHostPolicy=true to the below yaml spec:
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - -gRPC=32767
        - -tlsEnabled=false

So, the final spec will look like:
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - -gRPC=32767
        - -tlsEnabled=false
        - -enableKubeArmorHostPolicy=true

I tried saving the yaml file using kubectl get daemonset -n kubearmor -o yaml > daemonset.yaml and then using sed -i '/args:/a \          - -enableKubeArmorHostPolicy=true' daemonset.yaml to change and then apply the new daemonset.
But this approach gives an error:
for: "daemonset.yaml": error when patching "daemonset.yaml": Operation cannot be fulfilled on daemonsets.apps "kubearmor-bpf-containerd-98c2c": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again

